# How to get the all Drives via metricbeat?

Tags: configuration, elastic-stack, metricbeat

I have three drives, want to get three drives in kibana but I am able to get only one drive. I have added the name of those drives in system.yml configuration file but still, only one /dev/xvda1 is getting in kibana.

My Disks are:

```
[vinit@ip-XXX-XX-X-XXX modules.d]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       99G   30G   69G  31% /
devtmpfs        2.0G   56K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
```

System.yml configuration is:

```
# Module: system
# Docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/6.5/metricbeat-module-system.html

- module: system
  period: 10s
  metricsets:
    - cpu
    #- load
    - memory
    #- network
    #- process
    #- process_summary
    #- core
    #- diskio
    #- socket
  process.include_top_n:
    by_cpu: 5      # include top 5 processes by CPU
    by_memory: 5   # include top 5 processes by memory

- module: system
  period: 1m
  metricsets:
    - filesystem
    - fsstat
  processors:
  - drop_event.when.regexp:
      system.filesystem.mount_point: '^/(sys|cgroup|proc|dev|etc|devtmpfs|tmpfs|host|lib)($|/)'

- module: system
  period: 15m
  metricsets:
    - uptime

#- module: system
#  period: 5m
#  metricsets:
#    - raid
#  raid.mount_point: '/'
```

And I'm getting in kibana is:
[image]

Does anyone have any idea how to get these disks using metricbeat to logstash to kibana?

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, metricbeat comes with a pre-configured exclusion rule in `processors` block. Take a look at these lines:

```
processors:
  - drop_event.when.regexp:
      system.filesystem.mount_point: '^/(sys|cgroup|proc|dev|etc|devtmpfs|tmpfs|host|lib)($|/)'
```

Basically it means that all the events that match the regexp `'^/(sys|cgroup|proc|dev|etc|devtmpfs|tmpfs|host|lib)($|/)'` are going to be discarded, including this two:

```
devtmpfs        2.0G   56K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable answer it's partially working for me but only for those who start with / keyword like /dev/xvda1 and / /dev/mapper/ubuntu but still drives which start without / are not getting like devtmpfs and tmpfs. I commented this completely : 'processors:
  - drop_event.when.regexp:
      system.filesystem.mount_point: '^/(sys|cgroup|proc|dev|etc|devtmpfs|tmpfs|host|lib)($|/)''

Comment: I am also facing same issue, I want to discard "/dev/vda1" so i added it in regexp mentioned above but it is not working. Did you find any solution for that?

Comment: @RunSmeagolRun Keep in mind that the filter is over `system.filesystem.mount_point` so if you want to discard `/dev/vda1` whose mount point is, for example, `/media` you have to include *media* in the filter, not `/dev/vda1`.

Comment: @VinitJordan The filter starts with a slash (/), so if you want to discard a `system.filesystem.mount_point` that does not start with /, remove it or add another filter.

Comment: @ddiazp thanks for your valuable information it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

worked on metricbeat 8.4.2

```
- module: system
  period: 5m
  metricsets:
    - filesystem
    - fsstat
  filesystem.ignore_types: [tmpfs, smbfs, autofs]# to include nfs this string must have, cause of auto-ignoring all nodev devices listed in /proc/filesystems
  processors:
  - drop_event.when.regexp:
      system.filesystem.mount_point: '^/(sys|boot|cgroup|proc|dev|etc|host|lib|snap)($|/)'
```

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer.